# Converting array indices to objects in a hash in one line

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, dictionary, hash

Given an array

`array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']`

and a hash

`hash = {"a"=>1,"b"=>2,"c"=>3,"d"=>4,"e"=>5,"f"=>6}`

I would like to create a new array which contains the objects corresponding to the value of every index from the third onward. I am currently doing it like this:

```
newArray = []
array[2..-1].each do |item|
  newArray << hash[item]
end
```

I feel like this could be done in one line (possibly without creating the `newArray` beforehand as I would like to put this directly into another object's initialization code). Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to do it one line, just remove the linebreaks. In Ruby, you can always remove all linebreaks in all programs, by either replacing them with semicolons, keywords, or sometimes even nothing. In your case: `newArray = []; array[2..-1].each do |item| newArray << hash[item] end` Voilà: one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`Hash#values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at)

```
hash.values_at *array[2..-1]
# => [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
array[2..-1].map{|x| hash[x]}
```

could you post some expected example output please?

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.keep_if {|k,v| array.slice(2, array.length-2).index(k) }.values
```

or

```
hash.dup.keep_if {|k,v| array.slice(2, array.length-2).index(k) }.values
```

if you need to maintain the original hash values

Answer (score 0):

```
array[2..-1].inject([]) {|ary, x| ary << hash[x]}
```